# Scipy library similarity score calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to compute similarity scores using vectors:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
x = [1,2,4]
y = [1,3,5]
d = distance.cdist(x, y, 'seuclidean', V=None)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> ValueError: XA must be a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: The cdist docstring has an example of its use. Read that, try again, and come back explaining your road blocks

Answer (score 0):

First off you need to use NumPy arrays for input arrays and the error is telling you they need to be 2-D (as column vectors in this case). So:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
import numpy as np
x = [1,2,4]
y = [1,3,5]
x = np.array(x).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(y).reshape(-1, 1)
x
array([[1],
       [2],
       [4]])
y
array([[1],
       [3],
       [5]])

d = distance.cdist(x, y, 'seuclidean', V=None)
d
array([[ 0.        ,  1.22474487,  2.44948974],
       [ 0.61237244,  0.61237244,  1.83711731],
       [ 1.83711731,  0.61237244,  0.61237244]])
```

There are many method in the [`distance`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) module that do calculate a similarity (distance) between two vectors. A common example is [`cosine`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cosine).

```
x = [1,2,4]
y = [1,3,5]
distance.cosine(x, y)
0.0040899966895213691
```

Comment: I don't understand. The distance between two vectors is a scalar?

Comment: @im281 [`cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) calculates pair wise distance. Perhaps you were looking for [`scipy.spatial.distance.seuclidean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.seuclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.seuclidean)?

Comment: yes you might be right. I am looking for a scalar score of similarity between two vectors...